# Find the entire linear transformation with fixed point $1 + 2i$ that maps the point $i$ into the point $−i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Problem: Find the entire linear transformation with fixed point $1 + 2i$ that maps the point $i$ into the point $−i$.**

I drew a diagram to help myself.

[image: transformation]

I tried three different approaches.

**Approach 1**

Since fixed point, we have $f(1, 2) = 1 + 2i$ and $f(0, 1) = -i$. Without knowing $f$, I don't see what else I can do with this.

**Approach 2**

If I knew a three points in the z plane, there is a formula I could use. However, I essentially have two points in each of the z and w planes. In z plane I have $i$ and $1+2i$. That's not enough.

**Approach 3**

Here I'm thinking that if I contract $i$ by $\sqrt{2}$, rotate by some angle, and dilate by $\sqrt{10}$ I would get to $-i$. However, I realized that's not a general solution and works only for $i$.

---

Is there another approach I should take?

Comment: Did you try with $f(z)=a z+b$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear transformation (or Möbius transformation) is uniquely determined
by the values at three different points in the extended plane $\hat {\mathbb C}$. An *entire* linear transformation
is a Möbius transformation $T$ which has no poles in $\mathbb C$, in
other words, $T(\infty) = \infty$. Therefore the values at two
points in $\mathbb C$ are sufficient to determine $T$ uniquely.

Entire linear transformations are of the form
$$
T(z) = az + b
$$
with constants $a, b \in \mathbb C$ which can be determined
from $T(1+2i) = 1+2i$ and $T(i) = -i$.

It becomes a little bit easier if you note that an entire linear transformation with
fixed point $z_0 \in \mathbb C$ can be written as
$$
 T(z) - z_0 = \lambda (z - z_0)
$$
for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$. In your case $z_0 = 1+2i$,
and $\lambda$ can be determined from the requirement $T(i) = -i$.